# Is there a way to have rlwrap automatically delete history files?

Tags: linux, unix, rlwrap

I am using rlwrap to give command history to sqlplus/rman/etc on a linux server. I can see the command history files such as .sqlplus_history being generated and because these are plain text files that could possible contain passwords, e.g. if a user enters 'connect username/password' inside of sqlplus, there is a security risk to keeping them indefinitely.

Is there an easier way then some kind of cron job that would remove the logs at regular intervals?

I was hoping for some kind of keywords that would trigger the removal of the log such as if the 'exit' or 'quit' commands are read the user leaves sqlplus and the .sqlplus_history log is removed. Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rlwrap` has many options to keep command lines out of the history list (and hence out of the history file), although not exactly in the way you describe (which I would not find as useful anyway)

- `rlwrap --forget-matching connect sqlplus` will not remember any input lines that contain the string `connect`
- Specifying a *negative* history size, like `rlwrap --histsize -3000` will treat the history file as read-only (the password will still be visible in the history, but it will not be written to a file)
- Entering a line with `CTRL+O` will keep this particular line out of the history list. (This action can be re-bound to another key, see the manpage)

For a really fancy password censor, one could write a filter `censor_passwords` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib ($ENV{RLWRAP_FILTERDIR} or ".");
use RlwrapFilter;
use strict;

my $filter = new RlwrapFilter;

$filter -> help_text("This filter removes the password from SQL 'identified by' clauses\n");

$filter -> history_handler(sub { s/(identified\s+by\s+)(\S+)/$1 xXxXxXxX/ig; $_});

$filter -> run;
```

.. and then use it like `rlwrap -z censor_passwords sqlplus`.

Any input containing  `IDENTIFIED BY yd6e7#te6` will then be remembered as `IDENTIFIED BY xXxXxXxX`

Comment: That isn't exactly what I had in mind, but thanks for the help. The closest thing that might work is --forget-matching, i'll try that out.

Comment: What exactly _did_ you have in mind, then? That `rlwrap` would delete the whole history file whenever a keyword like `exit` is seen (and only then)? Or only the history of the current session? And what guarantee would that give that no passwords are kept? (after all, one can also end a session without using a keyword, e.g using `CTRL+D` of `CTRL+C`)